# Explode a table of elements and sub elements into a big table with all possible permutations

Tags: r

Appologies for the fuzzy Title, not sure how to describe what I'm trying to do... The example will be very clear so here it goes.

```
require (tibble)

#I have a (much larger) table of items that I need to turn into a very large lookup table  
ElementMatrix <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~Elements,
  "Gender",   "Male", 
  "Gender",   "Female", 
  "Smoking",   "Smoker", 
  "Smoking",   "Non-Smoker", 
  "Type1",   "A", 
  "Type1",   "B", 
  "Type1",   "C",
  "Type1",   NA
)

#into this
BigLookupMatrix <- tribble(
  ~Gender, ~Smoking, ~Type1,
  "Male", "Smoker", "A",
  "Male", "Smoker", "B",
  "Male", "Smoker", "C",
  "Male", "Smoker", NA,
  "Male", "Non-Smoker", "A",
  "Male", "Non-Smoker", "B",
  "Male", "Non-Smoker", "C",
  "Male", "Non-Smoker", NA,
  "Female", "Smoker", "A",
  "Female", "Smoker", "B",
  "Female", "Smoker", "C",
  "Female", "Smoker", NA,
  "Female", "Non-Smoker", "A",
  "Female", "Non-Smoker", "B",
  "Female", "Non-Smoker", "C",
  "Female", "Non-Smoker", NA
)

#I guessed it would be sonme gather / spready type thing, but that clearly doesnt work
gather(ElementMatrix, key=Category, value=Elements) #gives me back my origitional matrix
spread(ElementMatrix, key=Category, value=Elements) #gets angry about Duplicate identifiers
```

Now, I could obviously do a couple of nested loops, but that looks very messy. There must be a nice and clean way to do this.

Many thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a little base R with `unstack` and `expand.grid`?

```
expand.grid(unstack(ElementMatrix, Elements ~ Category))
   Gender    Smoking Type1
1    Male     Smoker     A
2  Female     Smoker     A
3    Male Non-Smoker     A
4  Female Non-Smoker     A
5    Male     Smoker     B
6  Female     Smoker     B
7    Male Non-Smoker     B
8  Female Non-Smoker     B
9    Male     Smoker     C
10 Female     Smoker     C
11   Male Non-Smoker     C
12 Female Non-Smoker     C
13   Male     Smoker  <NA>
14 Female     Smoker  <NA>
15   Male Non-Smoker  <NA>
16 Female Non-Smoker  <NA>
```

`unstack` will split up your Elements column by Category, here returning a named list. This is fed to `expand.grid`, which produces a data.frame with all combinations of the triple (Gender-Smoking-Type1).

Comment: WOW, thanks!
Quick newby question: What does the ~ do, that operator continues to mystify me...

Comment: It is used in a number of contexts (most predominantly in model formulas for functions like `lm` and `glm`). You can think of it here as "group Elements by category". As another example, the function `aggregate` performs group-level aggregation. An example from the help file (`?aggregate`) shows `aggregate(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean)` which can said "calculate the mean weight of chicks by feed type."

Comment: A very mysterious operator, but I think I am getting closer to understanding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it within the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

ElementMatrix %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(Elements = list(Elements)) %>%
  spread(Category, Elements) %>%
  as.list() %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  arrange(Gender, Smoking, Type1)
```